# How to extract paragraphs from pdf?

Tags: python, parsing, pdf, nlp

I have a pdf downloaded from SSRN here: https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=4337484. The default file name is "SSRN-id4337484.pdf".

I then extract the text from the downloaded file using the `pdftotext` package:

```
from pdftotext import PDF

with open("SSRN-id4337484.pdf", "rb") as f:
    pdf = PDF(f)
```

Each page is lumped into one, long string with "\r\n" tags indicating line breaks. For example if I print page 2:

```
[In ]: pdf[2]
[Out]:
'Journal of AI\r\narticles which have been published in English Language.\r\n\r\n3. WHAT `IS CHATGPT?\r\nTo begin, we asked ChatGPT to explain itself. The prompt we started with was “What is ChatGPT?”. ChatGPT\r\ngenerated this response.\r\n“ChatGPT is a large language model trained by OpenAI. It is designed to generate human-like text based on a\r\ngiven prompt or context. It can be used for a variety of natural language processing tasks, such as text\r\ncompletion, conversation generation, and language translation”. (By ChatGPT January 23, 2023).\r\nAs a follow up, we used another prompt “How does it work?” To know how conversational it is, we\r\nintentionally wrote “How does it work?” instead of "How does ChatGPT work?”. It returned with the response\r\nbelow.\r\n“ChatGPT is based on a transformer architecture, a type of neural network that has been shown to be very\r\neffective for natural language processing tasks. It is trained on a large dataset of text, such as books and\r\narticles, and learns to generate text that is similar to the text it was trained on. When given a prompt or\r\ncontext, the model processes the input and generates a response. The response is generated one word at a\r\ntime, with the model predicting the next word based on the input and the words it has generated so far. The\r\nmodel uses attention mechanisms to focus on the most relevant parts of the input and generate a response\r\nthat is coherent and appropriate for the given context. After the training, the model can be fine-tuned on a\r\nspecific task such as question answering or dialogue generation by providing it with task-specific examples\r\nand fine-tuning the model on this data. It can also generate text in multiple languages by fine-tuning the\r\nmodel on the multilingual dataset or by providing the model with the language code” (By ChatGPT January\r\n23, 2023).\r\nThen the topic of conversation was changed to discuss COVID-19 and impacts on educational deliveries using\r\nthe prompt “Now discuss how COVID-19 has changed educational pedagogies.” Within seconds it wrote the\r\npassage below.\r\nThe COVID-19 pandemic has had a significant impact on the way education is delivered, with many schools\r\nand universities shifting to online or remote learning in order to comply with social distancing guidelines. This\r\nhas resulted in a rapid shift to digital and online pedagogy, as educators have had to quickly adapt to this\r\nnew mode of instruction.\r\nOne of the major changes that has occurred is the increased use of technology for teaching and learning. This\r\nhas included the use of online learning platforms, such as Zoom, Google Classroom and other video\r\nconferencing tools, as well as the use of digital materials, such as e-books, videos, and interactive activities.\r\nThis has allowed for increased flexibility and accessibility in the delivery of education, as students can now\r\naccess materials and participate in classes from anywhere with internet access.\r\nAdditionally, there has been a shift towards more self-directed and asynchronous learning, where students\r\nare given more autonomy in their learning and are able to complete coursework at their own pace. This\r\napproach allows students to work at a time that is convenient for them, and it can be beneficial for students\r\nwho may have other responsibilities or who may have difficulty attending live classes. However, the shift to\r\nonline learning has also highlighted the digital divide, where students in low-income or rural areas may not\r\nhave access to the technology or internet connectivity needed to fully participate in remote learning. And it\r\nalso brought challenges such as lack of interaction, lack of motivation and lack of accountability.\r\nOverall, COVID-19 has accelerated the adoption of technology and digital pedagogy in education, but it has\r\nalso highlighted the need for equity and accessibility in the delivery of education. The education system will\r\nhave to continue to adapt and evolve to meet the needs of students, teachers and parents during these\r\n\r\n54\r\n\r\n\x0c'`
​
```

I can of course print it nicely using the line breaks:

```
[In ]: pdf[2].split('\r\n')
[Out]: 
['Journal of AI',
 'articles which have been published in English Language.',
 '',
 '3. WHAT IS CHATGPT?',
 'To begin, we asked ChatGPT to explain itself. The prompt we started with was “What is ChatGPT?”. ChatGPT',
 'generated this response.',
 '“ChatGPT is a large language model trained by OpenAI. It is designed to generate human-like text based on a',
 'given prompt or context. It can be used for a variety of natural language processing tasks, such as text',
 'completion, conversation generation, and language translation”. (By ChatGPT January 23, 2023).',
 'As a follow up, we used another prompt “How does it work?” To know how conversational it is, we',
 'intentionally wrote “How does it work?” instead of "How does ChatGPT work?”. It returned with the response',
 'below.',
 '“ChatGPT is based on a transformer architecture, a type of neural network that has been shown to be very',
 'effective for natural language processing tasks. It is trained on a large dataset of text, such as books and',
 'articles, and learns to generate text that is similar to the text it was trained on. When given a prompt or',
 'context, the model processes the input and generates a response. The response is generated one word at a',
 'time, with the model predicting the next word based on the input and the words it has generated so far. The',
 'model uses attention mechanisms to focus on the most relevant parts of the input and generate a response',
 'that is coherent and appropriate for the given context. After the training, the model can be fine-tuned on a',
 'specific task such as question answering or dialogue generation by providing it with task-specific examples',
 'and fine-tuning the model on this data. It can also generate text in multiple languages by fine-tuning the',
 'model on the multilingual dataset or by providing the model with the language code” (By ChatGPT January',
 '23, 2023).',
 'Then the topic of conversation was changed to discuss COVID-19 and impacts on educational deliveries using',
 'the prompt “Now discuss how COVID-19 has changed educational pedagogies.” Within seconds it wrote the',
 'passage below.',
 'The COVID-19 pandemic has had a significant impact on the way education is delivered, with many schools',
 'and universities shifting to online or remote learning in order to comply with social distancing guidelines. This',
 'has resulted in a rapid shift to digital and online pedagogy, as educators have had to quickly adapt to this',
 'new mode of instruction.',
 'One of the major changes that has occurred is the increased use of technology for teaching and learning. This',
 'has included the use of online learning platforms, such as Zoom, Google Classroom and other video',
 'conferencing tools, as well as the use of digital materials, such as e-books, videos, and interactive activities.',
 'This has allowed for increased flexibility and accessibility in the delivery of education, as students can now',
 'access materials and participate in classes from anywhere with internet access.',
 'Additionally, there has been a shift towards more self-directed and asynchronous learning, where students',
 'are given more autonomy in their learning and are able to complete coursework at their own pace. This',
 'approach allows students to work at a time that is convenient for them, and it can be beneficial for students',
 'who may have other responsibilities or who may have difficulty attending live classes. However, the shift to',
 'online learning has also highlighted the digital divide, where students in low-income or rural areas may not',
 'have access to the technology or internet connectivity needed to fully participate in remote learning. And it',
 'also brought challenges such as lack of interaction, lack of motivation and lack of accountability.',
 'Overall, COVID-19 has accelerated the adoption of technology and digital pedagogy in education, but it has',
 'also highlighted the need for equity and accessibility in the delivery of education. The education system will',
 'have to continue to adapt and evolve to meet the needs of students, teachers and parents during these',
 '',
 '54',
 '',
 '\x0c']
```

My question is how to extract paragraphs from those long strings into a list? So each paragraph is an element in that list. Note that sometimes one paragraph can span across two pages.

Answer (score 0):

had the same problem yesterday...

was hoping some python module would try an extract document structure based on styling, but could not find one. anyone please ping me if you know one!

in the meantime, I've used regex to identify end of §.
You're lucky enough that your data seams well punctuated so you can use that to identify end of §. Identifying the end of page is very ad hoc though, you might have to adjust to how other page end look like...

```
paragraph=""
paragraphs=[]
prev=""

for page in pdf:
    for lgn in page.split("\r\n"):
        if len(lgn)==0 :
            # setting tag to identify if empty line is first or second
            if prev=="empty":
                prev="empty2"
            elif prev=="pageNum" or prev=="pageEnd" : # skips empty lines at page end
                next
            else:
                prev="empty"
        # setting tag to identify if empty line is end of page
        elif re.search("^[0-9]*$",lgn) :
            prev="pageNum"
        elif lgn=='\x0c':
            # setting tag to identify end of page
            prev="pageEnd"
        # paragraph end
        elif lgn[-1] in ".?!" or len(lgn)<90:
            # end of § - see if other punctuations need to be added
            if prev=="empty":
                paragraphs.append("")
                prev=""
            if prev=="empty2":
                paragraphs.append("")
                paragraphs.append("")
                prev=""
            paragraphs.append(paragraph.strip()+" "+lgn[0:len(lgn)])
            paragraph=""
        # line is not empty nor end of page nor end of §
        else :
            paragraph=paragraph+" "+lgn
```

paragraphs

```
3. WHAT `IS CHATGPT?

[' Journal of AI',
 ' articles which have been published in English Language.',
 '',
 ' 3. WHAT `IS CHATGPT?',
 'To begin, we asked ChatGPT to explain itself. The prompt we started with was “What is ChatGPT?”. ChatGPT generated this response.',
 '“ChatGPT is a large language model trained by OpenAI. It is designed to generate human-like text based on a given prompt or context. It can be used for a variety of natural language processing tasks, such as text completion, conversation generation, and language translation”. (By ChatGPT January 23, 2023).',
 'As a follow up, we used another prompt “How does it work?” To know how conversational it is, we intentionally wrote “How does it work?” instead of "How does ChatGPT work?”. It returned with the response below.',
 '“ChatGPT is based on a transformer architecture, a type of neural network that has been shown to be very effective for natural language processing tasks. It is trained on a large dataset of text, such as books and articles, and learns to generate text that is similar to the text it was trained on. When given a prompt or context, the model processes the input and generates a response. The response is generated one word at a time, with the model predicting the next word based on the input and the words it has generated so far. The model uses attention mechanisms to focus on the most relevant parts of the input and generate a response that is coherent and appropriate for the given context. After the training, the model can be fine-tuned on a specific task such as question answering or dialogue generation by providing it with task-specific examples and fine-tuning the model on this data. It can also generate text in multiple languages by fine-tuning the model on the multilingual dataset or by providing the model with the language code” (By ChatGPT January 23, 2023).',
 'Then the topic of conversation was changed to discuss COVID-19 and impacts on educational deliveries using the prompt “Now discuss how COVID-19 has changed educational pedagogies.” Within seconds it wrote the passage below.',
 'The COVID-19 pandemic has had a significant impact on the way education is delivered, with many schools and universities shifting to online or remote learning in order to comply with social distancing guidelines. This has resulted in a rapid shift to digital and online pedagogy, as educators have had to quickly adapt to this new mode of instruction.',
 'One of the major changes that has occurred is the increased use of technology for teaching and learning. This has included the use of online learning platforms, such as Zoom, Google Classroom and other video conferencing tools, as well as the use of digital materials, such as e-books, videos, and interactive activities.',
 'This has allowed for increased flexibility and accessibility in the delivery of education, as students can now access materials and participate in classes from anywhere with internet access.',
 'Additionally, there has been a shift towards more self-directed and asynchronous learning, where students are given more autonomy in their learning and are able to complete coursework at their own pace. This approach allows students to work at a time that is convenient for them, and it can be beneficial for students who may have other responsibilities or who may have difficulty attending live classes. However, the shift to online learning has also highlighted the digital divide, where students in low-income or rural areas may not have access to the technology or internet connectivity needed to fully participate in remote learning. And it also brought challenges such as lack of interaction, lack of motivation and lack of accountability.',
 'Overall, COVID-19 has accelerated the adoption of technology and digital pedagogy in education, but it has also highlighted the need for equity and accessibility in the delivery of education. The education system will have to continue to adapt and evolve to meet the needs of students, teachers and parents during these blabla suite du text that is more than 90 caracters sqmùskdlùs klsdùklfsdùklfqùsd lmsdlk f*qsmdkf msmfk  next line that is  more than 90 caracters blablablablaa adjfùsd fklsmdkfs dmslkd flsmdlkfs dmslfdks fs end of line.']
```